# Can boost/random/uniform_int.hpp and boost/random/uniform_int_distribution.hpp be used interchangeably?

Tags: c++, boost, random

There are two random integer generators in boost, `boost::uniform_int<>` and `boost::random::uniform_int_distribution<>`, the latter being add only after boost 1.47.

I would like to know if there is any difference in their performance (i.e. the quality of the random numbers they generate)?

Also, with `boost::uniform_int<>` you need to couple it with a random engine through `variate_generate`, but seems on [boost's official website](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/boost_random.html) that you can use

```
boost::random::mt19937 rng;
boost::random::uniform_int_distribution<> six(1,6);
int x = six(rng);
```

wihout the variate generate.

Can these two usage be used interchangeably?

Answer (score 1):

`boost::uniform_int<>` inherits from `boost::random::uniform_int_distribution<>` and if you look at the [header](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/boost/random/uniform_int.hpp) for `uniform_int<>`, you can see that it basically just calls the base class functions.

Since `uniform_int<>` just calls `uniform_int_distribution<>`'s functions, there is no difference in the numbers generated. Boost does explicitly state, however, that `uniform_int<>` is deprecated, and that `uniform_int_distribution<>` should be used for all new code.

To answer your second question, neither `uniform_int<>` nor `uniform_int_distribution<>` require a `boost::random::variate_generator<>` to function. The `variate_generator<>` simply associates a random number generator (like `boost::random::mt19937`) with a random number distribution (like `uniform_int_distribution<>`) as a convenience. If you don't use `variate_generator<>`, then you need to pass a random number generator each time you wish to generate a random number. Here's an example:

```
#include <boost/random/uniform_int.hpp>
#include <boost/random/mersenne_twister.hpp>
#include <boost/random/variate_generator.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

int main()
{
  boost::mt19937 rand_generator(std::time(NULL));
  boost::random::uniform_int_distribution<> int_distribution(0, 100);

  //Need to pass generator
  std::cout << int_distribution(rand_generator) << std::endl;

  //Associate generator with distribution
  boost::random::variate_generator<boost::mt19937&,
                                   boost::random::uniform_int_distribution<>
                                   > int_variate_generator(rand_generator, int_distribution);

  //No longer need to pass generator
  std::cout << int_variate_generator() << std::endl;
}
```

Note that the first call is to `uniform_int_distribution<> operator()` whereas the second call is to `variate_generator<> operator()`. Associating a generator with a distribution does not change the original generator or distribution objects.

Please let me know if anything is unclear.